# Pass Vector Axis by Reference and Update

Tags: c#, vector, unity-game-engine, pass-by-reference

I am trying to pass a particular axis of a vector by reference.  I know there are several ways to accomplish this same thing, but my objective is to only pass in a single argument (the Vector's x, y, or z) and for that Vector to be updated.  How can I accomplish this?  This is what I am trying to do, but obviously does not work:

```
private void MainMethod()
{
    Vector3 myVector = new Vector3(1, 2, 3);
    ChangeVector(ref myVector.x);
    ChangeVector(ref myVector.y);

    //this should all be true
    bool newX = myVector.x == 4; //true
    bool newY = myVector.y == 4; //true
    bool newZ = myVector.z == 3; //true
}

private void ChangeVector(ref Vector3.axis myVectorAxis)
{
    myVectorAxis = 4;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Vector3` components are simply `floats`, I don't see any reason to do that. Btw the signature of your `ChangeVector` functions is wrong. It should eventually be something like:

```
private void ChangeVector(ref float myVectorAxis)
{
    myVectorAxis = 4f;
}
```

Comment: ya, i know. that was moreso psudeo code. im going to try the code u just posted tho. that may actually work :)